# ActiveMQ - Threads per producer for Queues

Tags: activemq-classic, jmeter

I am trying to do some stress testing on AMQ 5.5.1.

I have created a queue and using Jmeter Point-to-point to send JMS requests to the queue. Kindly note I haven't configured any consumer so mesages just get stacked up and actually stored in KahaDB store.
I notice if I have used 200 users in the Thread group - it creates exactly 400 threads on ActiveMQ that I can see via jconsole.
Jmeter slowly(actually quite fast) keeps on pushing messages to the queue as I can see the queue size gradually increasing and doesn't do it at one go.

I am using ProducerFlowControl as false and using the default hybrid store cursor on (though I haven't got a ready consumer at the moment).

I am also using Persistent Delivery.

My questions are:

1. What is restricting Jmeter from pushing all the 200 messages at one go? Is it ActiveMQ or I need to configure something in jmeter to be able to send 200 at one go. I did notice as soon as I start the test on Jmeter straight away 400 threads are created on ActiveMQ which makes me think it establishes connections at one go for 200 users with activemq but messages are pushed in batches but not together.
2. Why are there 2 threads per consumer on activemq and why do all the threads remain active until all messages have been pushed. Ideally if the users were pushing messages one by one as soon as they have done so and got an acknowledgement back it should have died out. But all 200 X 2 threads die at the same time when all messages have finally been pushed.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: any help guys? I am sure lot of people must have noticed this behaviour